# Java Hashmap. How many maximum records should it be used for?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, hashmap

I have 10,000 mappings. Will it be a good idea to put them all in a java Hashmap and access ? This will save database transactions as all 10,000 records will be present in memory itself. Every mapping will have around 100 characters including key and value and mappings will be quite distinct. Asking this question since don't have great experience in java or on similar situation.

Comment: HashMaps don't care what you put in them; they auto-expand when new data are added. Your RAM does, though, but even the smallest memory these days is about one gigabyte for the most low-end, netbook-ish computers.

Answer (score 7):

10K objects is a drop in the bucket (pardon the pun) as far as memory goes.

Try it and see, but I think you'll find even the most modest memory capacity these days will handle it. Make sure you have a reasonable heap size: `-Xmx512m` or whatever

Answer (score 1):

Should not be a problem. Things to be careful about:

1. Create your HashMap instance with the expected capacity to avoid having to resize the map as you add your 10K items.
2. Make sure your key has a good `hashcode` and matching `equals` implementation. If you are using something like a String as your key, this is already done for you.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So if in future the number of records to be added to my Hashmap increase to be more than the capacity it is instantiated, it will actually get resized and Hashmap will still continue working the way it should. Correct ?

Comment: Yes, the map continues to work. What you would see is constant-time `put` operations until you hit the capacity and the map decided to resize. When this happens, it allocates a new (bigger) store and inserts each existing item into the new store. It allocates extra space, so your `put`s go back to being fast again until it needs to grow again. Having it grow is generally not a problem, but if you know ahead of time that you are going to insert some number of items, you might as well allocated it that big to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of HashMap.size() is integer.

int     HashMap.size() (Returns the number of key-value mappings in this map.)

So you can store upto maximum of 2,147,483,647 objects.

int ->  The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive).

To store maximum values into map you need to increase your heap size(depends on your need).

Answer (score 0):

How big your elements to be mapped are?

It depends on the size of the elements that you want and the available size on the JVM, but in most of the cases it is feasible to have 10,000 mappings.